# Java - getting type of derivated class

Tags: java

So I have an abstract class named "User" and two derivated classes named "Seller" and "Buyer". I also have a vector of users in which I push sellers and buyers... My question is: if I get a random element from vector, how can I know if the element it's seller or buyer?
Thanks

Comment: The more interesting question is: why do you have to know? Your classes themselves should know what to do. But if you want to stick to a broken design try `instanceof`.

Comment: Any need to know what specific subtype of a parent class you are looking at is serious code smell. Rethink your logic.

Answer (score 0):

use `isInstanceOf(Object);` on the random object with an if() condition to check if it' a a buyer or a seller